# What is the $10$-nth derivative of the function $f(x)$ at $x = 0$?

Tags: calculus

> What is the $10$-nth derivative of the function $f(x)$ at $x = 0$?
> $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
> \frac{e^{x}-1}{x} & \text { for } & x \neq 0 \\
> 1 & \text { for } & x=0
> \end{array}\right.$$

According to the source I am using the answer is $\frac{1}{11}$ but I don't see that. I am supposed to get to this answer in a few minutes so I think I am missing something here that simplifies this problem.

Edit: I used a hint. I have put $\sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in place of $e^x$. Then when I differentiate $10$ times I have a term $\frac{x^0}{11}$ because other terms vanish, bigger ones vanish at $x=0$ and smaller terms vanish when they get to $x^0$ and get differentiated again. There are 2 terms that may seem problematic at first, but luckily one is $\frac{1}{x}$ and the other is $\frac{-1}{x}$ so they cancel. Nice.

Comment: Use the power series of $e^x$.

Comment: OP updated the question. I don't think there's a need to close/downvote

Comment: Good, Naah. Write it up, and post it as an answer.